# Specific Hedge Fund Filed Returns

Tags: options

https://mebfaber.com/2008/12/27/tracking-jim-simons-renaissance-technologies/

But, like always, I will let the data speak for itself.  Top 10 holdings, back to 2000, equal weighted through 12/19/2008:

Fund Data
Annualized Return: -9.8%
Volatility: 19.5%
MaxDD: -69.1%
(Max DD is maximum peak to valley drawdown, measured monthly.)

Maybe, just maybe they didn't do that good?

Else

But why are they so bad at us stock investing?

Why do they make their no employee funds bad for no reason?

And by the way 13f is the net long position, any hedge position which is net long would appear. Sales would appear as well so the information has to be accurate. I guess the answer is assuming only their short positions matter? Sounds strange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is that these simulated performance based on public filings is more or less useless.

1. 13Fs are only filed on a quarterly basis with a meaningful delay. By the time you see the filings, the positions may have changed drastically.
2. 13Fs only include US long positions. We don't know what shorts are paired against these longs; we don't know what derivatives are in the portfolio; and we have no visibility into non-US holdings.
3. Along the same line, because of RT's trading style, we have no insights into why a position exists in the first place. Did they buy a stock because they liked the company, or is it part of a sector bet, or is it just a placeholder for some unknown factor? Without these insights, blindly following the positions can be problematic. So 13Fs are really only useful if we are tracking a low turnover, mostly long-only investor making equity investments in the US. This is mostly true for funds/companies like Berkshire (concentrated long positions in the US, and he buys companies because he likes them), but this does not fit RT's profile at all.
4. When people talk about RT's stellar performance, they're mostly referring to the Medallion fund. Some performance statistics can be found [here](http://www.mysmu.edu/faculty/christophert/Reading/Inside%20a%20Moneymaking%20Machine%20Like%20no%20Other.pdf). Medallion is closed and only has employee money at this point (I could be wrong). RT's other funds that are offered to external clients are nowhere near as good, based on what I've read.

Comment: And why would they intentionally make their customer funds bad?

Comment: 1) already accounted 2) sales are reported also, so any combination of long/short would involve a sale 3) irrelevant 4) irrelevant

Comment: @user43376 The key message I'd say I'm trying to convey is that you can't say much of anything from these filings. For example, short positions are not required to be disclosed and are generally not reported on 13Fs. They could be holding positions for months or seconds, we just don't know; this is just a snapshot of their longs at a point in time. All evidence points to them being very good at trading US stocks. They are also not intentionally making their customer funds bad. These funds use different strategies, which generate different returns. There's nothing unacceptable about it.

Comment: @user43376 I haven't followed them closely for a while, but my impression is that their client funds are fairly typical quant strats (styles/factors). (Please correct me if i'm wrong). Presumably they think their implementations of these classical strats are superior and add value for clients. They likely closed Medallion because 1) they don't want to disclose much of anything about what they're doing in it to clients, and 2) they may just have run out of capacity and they can't take on client money anymore in those strats.

Comment: Yeah it does have any short hedge positions because that is how they are handled on the 13F. There are no disclosure requirements for customers either. 2) is the only valid reason so far but that sounds like a crappy strat